# Empty diff window with Apply Patch in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

Steps:

1. Use TortoiseSVN's context menu to select "Create Patch"
2. On another machine do the same but select "Apply Patch" and select the file generated in step 1.
3. A blank merge window is opened.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The patch file is valid and I can use unix patch to apply it successfully (with some line-ending tinkering).

I'm on Windows 10 and TortoiseSVN/TortoiseMerge 1.9.5

Comment: (This is not the same as the [blank error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940172/tortoisesvn-apply-patch-error) problem.)

Comment: The same is true for TortoiseGit/TortoiseGitMerge 2.8.0.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem was that TortoiseMerge was maximized. There's a floating window on the left.

Unmaximize the TortoiseMerge window and you can see the file selector window. You can select files in that window to see them in the diff view and there's buttons for applying the patch.

It should look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had to select TortoiseMerge for <kbd>Settings</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>Diff Viewer</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>Merge Tool</kbd>.

I previously configured an external editor here and then it did not show this patch window but only an empty merge tool. Maybe this feature does not work very well with external editors.