# Need for stable alternative to TortoiseMerge for applying patches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is the clear error message I get when I try to apply a patch with TortoiseMerge is there a solution / alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940172/tortoisesvn-apply-patch-error).

There are 3 possible root causes to this empty error:

1. the patch file is empty (or is invalid so the patch data appears to be empty)
2. the patch is not applied to the correct directory
3. the patch file uses absolute paths instead of relative ones

Additionally, I suggest you to run the `patch` command with the `--verbose` option in command line to apply your patch, and check the output.